# Orbited exception Data must not be unicode

Tags: orbited

I am working with orbited and once I switch on orbited in production mode it throws the following error on my screen

`-- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 150, in process
    self.render(resrc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 157, in render
    body = resrc.render(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/orbited-0.7.10-py2.6.egg/orbited/transports/base.py", line 21, in render
    self.conn.transportOpened(self)`

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/orbited-0.7.10-py2.6.egg/orbited/cometsession.py", line 322, in transportOpened
    self.cometTransport.flush()`

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/orbited-0.7.10-py2.6.egg/orbited/transports/base.py", line 45, in flush
    self.write(self.packets)`

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/orbited-0.7.10-py2.6.egg/orbited/transports/htmlfile.py", line 42, in write
    self.request.write(payload);`

`File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 862, in write
    self.transport.write(data)`

`File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 420, in write
    abstract.FileDescriptor.write(self, bytes)`

`File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 170, in write
    raise TypeError("Data must not be unicode")`

`exceptions.TypeError: Data must not be unicode`

I have absolutely no clue as to what could be the problem. Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that has worked for me now is upgrading to orbited 0.8. Though its still in development mode, it works well and resolves the issue. The issue lies in the proxy.py file which has been resolved in the 0.8 release.

Hope this helps